# Type script error in angular material rowHeight

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular and angular material to create a mat-grid-list with the code below

template

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" [rowHeight]="rowHeight | async">
```

component

```js
  rowHeight = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
    map(({ matches }) => {
      if (matches) {
        return "1500px"
      }

      return "500px"
    }),
    startWith("500px"),
    catchError(_ => { return "500px" })
  );
```

But there is a compiling error saying

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | number'.

3   <mat-grid-list cols="2" [rowHeight]="rowHeight | async">
```

It looks like my `rowHeight` in component return null in a way, but couldn't figure it out how to avoid this...

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `AsyncPipe`s return `null` if the `Observable` hasn't produced any values yet.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Carcigenicate for the hint above, I understood what the problems is.
So I came up with something like this, and no compiling error anymore.

```html
  <mat-grid-list
    cols="2"
    [rowHeight]="rowHeightNotNull"
    *ngIf="rowHeight | async as rowHeightNotNull"
  >
```

But still expecting something better...why the startWith() doesnot work...?